# Automated Android platform testing

Tags: android, testing, deployment, sdk

Does anyone know of a service or application that allows me to test an app on multiple system images, automatically?  Given the incompatibilities between Sense, TouchWiz, and Motoblur, I find that my app will work fine in the SDK emulator and on my phone/tablet, but will crash horribly on another version of the UI or OS.  If not, I'm tempted to crack at making my own, but I'd like to avoid it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://testdroid.com/) is a service that can be useful for you. I did not use it so I cannot tell you about its possibilities. Moreover, some people use different servers like Jenkins to create a test system for their applications but these systems can check applications on different configurations of emulator not real phones.